# Is there any info available on how to measure daily eating calories perfectly?

Tags: diet, calories, daily-caloric-intake, diet-tools

I am trying the measuring calorie eating for reducing fat but couldn't find a way to measure the calories i am eating ..Is there any ways to do this perfectly ?

thanks

Shihab

Comment: Questions only related to Nutrition are off topic on the site, according to the [FAQ]. Check out the [Nutrition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition?referrer=60gsuPikc4OEtIT3irFQMg2) proposal on Area51.

Comment: To give you a simple answer: Look up everything you eat, eg using google (search for calories [banana, meat, milk, etc]) and summarize. You don't need to do this perfectly as you will never exactly know how much you burned. Measuring Calories is a very inaccurate measurement.

Comment: there are smartphone apps / websites like "myfitnesspal" or "Livestrong MyPlate" that have imperfect calorie estimates based on foods that you enter.  I've used those in the past with success to track my meals.

Comment: This question is off-topic as defined by the [FAQ](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). Feel free to revisit your question and modify it so that it fits within the scope defined for this site in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to perfectly measure the number of calories you consume every day. Your best bet is use a website, such as [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com) to get a rough estimate.

Comment: Nothing in this answer that hasn't been said in the comments.

Comment: That's okay, though, right? Often, people leave comments that are better said as an answer.

Comment: I agree. I think this answer is accurate in terms of the question, even if it is just a summation of the comments on the question.